# c# inserting string in middle of string

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a pretty long string. Before I databind the string, I want to be able to modify the string by inserting some more text. For example, I have a string `<a href="/a/info/a.html"><img src="/userimage/imgs.jpg"/></a>` I need to insert http://m.mydom.com right before the /a and right before /userimage. Note, this will always be the same so it is safe to say that the string I want to add to will be consistent. I would like to do this either with lamda or just c#. Thanks for any help.

Comment: So is the user not currently on http://m.mydom.com?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to do this for all relative paths on your page, using C# to accomplish this is actually not the best tool for this.

HTML comes with an element called [`base` (see spec information)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.4) that is used to specify a document's base URI explicitly.  If you changed your HTML to something like the following:

```
<head>
    <base href="http://m.mydom.com">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="/a/info/a.html"><img src="/userimage/imgs.jpg"/></a>
</body>
```

Both the image and the anchor will point to the correct base.  Don't believe me?  Check out this [jsFiddle demonstating the amazingness of `base`](http://jsfiddle.net/WWxZF/).

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx)?

```
var s = "<a href=\"/a/info/a.html\"><img src=\"/userimage/imgs.jpg\"/></a>";
s.Replace("\"/a","\"http://m.mydom.com/a").Replace("\"/userimage", "\"http://m.mydom.com/userimage");
```

Not the nicest method, you could always use a RegEx.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple regular expression:

```
var regex = new Regex("(?<=(src|href)=\")([^\"]*)");
var s = "<a href=\"/a/info/a.html\"><img src=\"/userimage/imgs.jpg\"/></a>";
Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(s, "http://m.mydom.com$0"));
```

`(?<=...)` is a lookbehind; `$0` is the content of the capturing group `0`, which is the content of the link before the replacement.